# execution of commands multiple times without loops javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a function that I can use to execute commands multiple times...

```
alert('hi');
alert('hi');
alert('hi');
```

so that I can do this without repitition.

Is there a way to do this with a preset function to eliminate redundancy?

Comment: Loops would be the way to go, why don't you want to use them?

Comment: @danielR Well, if there was a more efficient way of doing it, why not?

Comment: If you use something more obscure that people don't know about rather than loops, your code is less readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Underscore.js ([website](http://underscorejs.org/)) ([GitHub](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore)), you can use times():

```
function sayHi() {
    alert('hi');
}

_.times(3, sayHi);
```

Comment: This isn't correct.  This will only call the `alert()` once.  You have to pass a function reference, not the return result of executing `alert()`.

Comment: Oops, duh. Let me fix that.

Answer (score 2):

The 'preset functionality' would simply be a loop, in one form or another. You could use Coffeescript's comprehensions:

```
alert('hi') for num in [1..10]
```

http://coffeescript.org/#loops

But that's still a loop :)

Some languages, like Ruby, have a construct like

```
10.times do { puts 'hi' }
```

Unfortunately, the same isn't available in JS.

Comment: Thanks, but would it fall under the category of conventional loops? (I dont have anything against loops just so you know)

Comment: Yes — the definition of loop in a programming context is a way to do something multiple times. You can layer syntax and structures on top to hide the loop, but (at least within the realm of 'recognizable' programs) it's still a loop.

Answer (score 2):

There is not something built into the Javascript language that lets you repeat a function multiple times, but you can easily create a function to do that for you:

```
function execMultiple(fn, num, /* args */) {
    // make copy of the args without the first two items
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        fn.apply(this, args);
    }
}

execMultiple(alert, 3, 'hi');
```

---

Or, you could require a stub function with args already in it be passed in:

```
function execN(fn, n) {
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        fn();
    }
}

execN(function() {
    alert('hi');
}, 3);
```